# pyspark how to do this conversion efficiently?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

i'm the newbie of pyspark, just known the most easiest operation of it.  and my english is very bad, sorry, i can't descripe it very detail, the following is the sample! thanks for your answers

- dataframe like this:

---

```
| name |    id | flag  | cnt |
| li   | 19196 | true  |  10 |
| li   | 19196 | false |  15 |
```

- i want to convert it to:

---

```
| name |    id | flag_true | flag_false |
| li   | 19196 |        10 |         15 |
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a pivot table for that:

```
df.groupBy(['name', 'id'])\
  .pivot('flag')\
  .agg(f.sum('cnt'))\
  .withColumnRenamed('true', 'flag_true')\
  .withColumnRenamed('false', 'flag_false')\
  .show()
```

That prints:

```
+----+-----+----------+---------+
|name|   id|flag_false|flag_true|
+----+-----+----------+---------+
|  li|19196|        15|       10|
+----+-----+----------+---------+
```